# additional fields based on the quantity of products selected

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field, email

I have to make a site to sell course enrollments and to do so I'm using woocomerce.
both single people and companies who will make multiple registrations for their employees will enroll in the courses, I would like to be able to have fields like the standard woocomerce checkout filled in if it is a single person.
Otherwise if it is a company (which I have to register more depends for the same course) standard fields for company data and fields for employee data that are repeated based on the quantity selected in the product.  Once the order is completed I need to see all the data on the order page and in the emails.
I tried [this plug-in][1], it works but I can't show a group of fields based on quantity, do you think this feature can be added somehow?  otherwise i found [this code][2]

```
function person_details( $checkout ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
    $i = 0;

    for( $k=1; $k<= $count; $k++ ) {
        $i++;
        print ('Dati iscritto n. '.$i.'');
        
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_full_name'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-first'),
            'label'         => __('Nome e cognome'),
            'placeholder'   => __(''),
            'required' => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_full_name'.$i ));
        
        
        
            woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_email'.$i, array(
                'type'          => 'email',
                'required' => true,
                'class'         => array( 'my-field-class form-row-last' ),
                'label'         => __( 'Email' ),
                
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_email'.$i ));
            
            woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_phone'.$i, array(
                'type'          => 'text',
                'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-first'),
                'label'         => __('Numero di telefono'),
                'placeholder'   => __(''),
                'required' => true,
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_phone'.$i ));
            
            woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_address'.$i, array(
                'type'          => 'textarea',
                'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-last'),
                'label'         => __('Indirizzo di residenza'),
                'placeholder'   => __(''),
                'required' => true,
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_address'.$i ));
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
            
        echo '<div class="clearbox"></div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'person_details' );
```

```
function customise_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
    $i = 0;
    for($k=1; $k<= $count; $k++) {
        $i++;
        if (!empty($_POST['cstm_full_name'.$i])) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'Nome e cognome'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_full_name'.$i]));
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['cstm_email'.$i])) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'email'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_email'.$i]));
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['cstm_phone'.$i])) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'Numero di telefono'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_phone'.$i]));
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['cstm_address'.$i])) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'Indirizzo di residenza'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_address'.$i]));
        }
        /*if ( isset( $_POST['cstm_groep'.$i] )){
            $value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cstm_groep'.$i] );
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'cstm_groep'.$i, $value );  
        }*/
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'customise_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function add_email_custom_order_meta( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ){

    $quantity = 0;      
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $quantity = $quantity + $item->get_quantity();
    }
    
    $order_id = $order->get_order_number();
    echo "<ul>";
        $i = 0;
        for( $k=1; $k <= $quantity; $k++ ) {
            $i++;
            echo "<li>Nome e cognome: ".get_post_meta($order_id, 'Nome e cognome'.$i, true )."</li>";
            echo "<li>Email: ".get_post_meta($order_id, 'Email'.$i, true )."</li>";
            echo "<li>Numero di telefono: ".get_post_meta($order_id, 'Numero di telefono'.$i, true )."</li>";
            echo "<li>Indirizzo di residenza: ".get_post_meta($order_id, 'Indirizzo di residenza'.$i, true )."</li>";
            
            
        }
    echo "</ul>";

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'add_email_custom_order_meta', 10, 3 );
```

```
// display the extra data in the order admin panel
function display_order_custom_data_in_admin_order_overview_page( $order ){  ?>
    <div class="order_data_column" style="width: 100% !important;">
        <h4><?php _e( 'Your label' ); ?></h4>
        <?php 
            $quantity = 0;      
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
                $quantity = $quantity + $item->get_quantity();
            }
            
            $order_id = $order->get_order_number();
            echo "<ul>";
                $i = 0;
                for( $k=1; $k <= $quantity; $k++ ) {
                    $i++;
                    echo "<li>Nome e cognome: ".get_post_meta($order_id, 'Nome e cognome'.$i, true )."</li>";
                    echo "<li>Email: ".get_post_meta($order_id, 'Email'.$i, true )."</li>";
                    echo "<li>Numero di telefono: ".get_post_meta($order_id, 'Numero di telefono'.$i, true )."</li>";
                    echo "<li>Indirizzo di residenza: ".get_post_meta($order_id, 'Indirizzo di residenza'.$i, true )."</li>";
                    
                }
            echo "</ul>";    
        ?>
    </div>
<?php }
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'display_order_custom_data_in_admin_order_overview_page' );
```

this works, it adds the fields based on the quantity but I can't see the data in the email and in the order page , and also I would like to put some conditions like if you select I'm a private person show i standard fields otherwise if you select I am a company it will show a group of fields to be filled in only once and more other groups of equal fields to be filled in, as many as the selected quantity.

the code is old maybe the hooks of woocomerce have changed over time, I tried to look but I could not make it work.  do you know if there is an easier way to do it like with some plugin or if you can mix some of the plugin mentioned above and the code?

for example using the fields and conditions of the plugin but choosing with the code which group of fields to show based on the quantity?
[1]: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-checkout-field-editor-pro/
[2]: https://wasimsama.com/woocommerce-dynamic-custom-field-on-checkout-based-on-product-quantity-in-cart/